# Placing return values of a multiprocessing function into a matrix

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

My actual problem is quite lengthy, and I believe it could benefit from multi-processing. The crux of the problem is as follows:
I have some multiprocessing function that takes in two values (x , y) outputs a single number Q. For illustration:

```
def multiprocessing_func(x , y):
        Q = x*y
```

(The actual function is much more complicated and involves running a simulation for input parameters x and y)
I have two arrays of x and y values e.g.:

```
x = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
y = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
```

I would like to compile the values of Q from `multiprocessing_func` into a matrix `Q_matrix`:

```
import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    processes = []
    
    for m in range(len(x)):
        for n in range(len(y)):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target = multiprocessing_func , args=(x[m] , y[n]))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
            
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

So far my attempts have involved using `return_dict` in my multiprocessing functions. The `return_dict` simply compiles all the return values in a list. However, of course, that gives the wrong dimensionality. Essentially, I am wondering if there is a multiprocessing equivalent of this set-up:

```
x = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
y = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
Q_matrix = np.zeros(shape = (len(x) , len(y)))
for m in range(len(x)):
    for n in range(len(y)):
        Q_matrix[m , n] = x[m]*y[n]
```

I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I am quite new to multi-processing so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a multiprocessing **Manager.array**? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers

Comment: @MarkSetchell There is no need to use a managed array. The worker function returns a value and the main process assigns it to the appropriate `Q_matrix[m][n] ` slot. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overhead in creating subprocesses and passing arguments to the processes that "live" in a different address space. So unless your worker function, `multiprocessing_func` is considerably more CPU-intensive than what you currently have to make this additional overhead worth the cost of using multiprocessing, you are better off not using it. But this is how you could using a multiprocessing pool whose size is limited by either the number of tasks you have to submit or the number of CPU cores you have.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import numpy as np
import os


def multiprocessing_func(x, y):
    return x * y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
    y = np.linspace(0 , 1 , 10)
    Q_matrix = np.zeros(shape = (len(x) , len(y)))
    pool_size = min(os.cpu_count(), len(x) * len(y))
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
        # create mapping between the Future instance returned by submit and the original m, n indexes:
        futures = {executor.submit(multiprocessing_func, x[m], y[n]): (m, n) for m in range(len(x)) for n in range(len(y))}
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            m, n = futures[future] # original indexes
            result = future.result()
            Q_matrix[m][n] = result
    print(Q_matrix)
```

Prints:

```
[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.01234568 0.02469136 0.03703704 0.04938272 0.0617284
  0.07407407 0.08641975 0.09876543 0.11111111]
 [0.         0.02469136 0.04938272 0.07407407 0.09876543 0.12345679
  0.14814815 0.17283951 0.19753086 0.22222222]
 [0.         0.03703704 0.07407407 0.11111111 0.14814815 0.18518519
  0.22222222 0.25925926 0.2962963  0.33333333]
 [0.         0.04938272 0.09876543 0.14814815 0.19753086 0.24691358
  0.2962963  0.34567901 0.39506173 0.44444444]
 [0.         0.0617284  0.12345679 0.18518519 0.24691358 0.30864198
  0.37037037 0.43209877 0.49382716 0.55555556]
 [0.         0.07407407 0.14814815 0.22222222 0.2962963  0.37037037
  0.44444444 0.51851852 0.59259259 0.66666667]
 [0.         0.08641975 0.17283951 0.25925926 0.34567901 0.43209877
  0.51851852 0.60493827 0.69135802 0.77777778]
 [0.         0.09876543 0.19753086 0.2962963  0.39506173 0.49382716
  0.59259259 0.69135802 0.79012346 0.88888889]
 [0.         0.11111111 0.22222222 0.33333333 0.44444444 0.55555556
  0.66666667 0.77777778 0.88888889 1.        ]]
```